# Access remote mongodb from node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to access the remote mongodb data through node. Have written following in my app.js :

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db = MongoClient.connect("mongodb://remote_url:27017/databasetest");
//db name is : databasetest

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  req.db = db;
  next();
});
```

Following is the api written to access a collection from the db:

```
router.get('/get', function(req, res, next) {
 var db = req.db;
 var collection = db.get('test');
 collection.find({},function(e,docs){
    res.json(docs);
 });
});
```

I am getting the following error while accessing the API :

**db.get is not a function**

Could someone help me for the same

Comment: A lot depends on your remote mongodb server as well, do you have a single server unit or do you have a unit with arbiters supporting the main unit. Please give us realistic information as well.

Answer (score 2):

The mongo db connection string has this format, you do not have username and password

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@<url>:<port>/<database>
```

For test connection, maybe is easy to play with a test account in mlab.com, it's free an only take two minutes.

1.First step test the connection

`var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;`

```
// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
});
```

//When you have tested this, replace

> console.log("We are connected");

for

```
db.collection('test').find( <your query> )
```

Comment: Have tried that too..adding **user:password** into the url.. but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using the recent version of the node.js MongoDB driver (currently at version 2.2.4).

One issue that immediately comes to mind is this line in your code:

```
var db = MongoClient.connect("mongodb://remote_url:27017/databasetest");
```

The `MongoClient.connect()` function requires a callback parameter, otherwise it will return a Promise. However, your subsequent code do not treat the variable `db` as a Promise.

Furthermore, you are trying to get (and set) the `db` variable from (and to) the `req` object. This `req` object contains the HTTP request and has properties for the request query string, parameters, body, HTTP headers, and so on. This is the source of the error you are seeing.

This is the minimal working example that I can get using Express to provide an equivalent to the command `db.test.find().toArray()` in the `mongo` shell:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var assert = require('assert')
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var db = null
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err,database) {
    assert.equal(err,null)
    db = database
})

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
    db.collection('test').find({}).toArray(function(err,doc) {
        assert.equal(err,null)
        res.send(JSON.stringify(doc))
    })
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 3000')
})
```

Note that in the above example, I'm using a global `db` variable to store the MongoDB database connection created by `MongoClient.connect()`. Feel free to experiment using Promises, if it feels more natural to you.

More details regarding the MongoClient class can be found in http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/MongoClient.html